# Specific file name search UNIX

Tags: unix, grep, find, new-operator

Hello i am new with UNIX and needed help with my search. I need to find a file that starts with 'f' than has unknown number of numbers then has 'gr' and ends with large letters also unknown number and unknown extension. ex. f123456grKNI, f11223grKE

Thank you up front

Comment: Are you sure it is really unix not linux? Unix is only used in ancient systems nowerdays.

Comment: Yeah its Unix, i have a subject from my studies :/ and i think i solved it and this is what i end up with `ls | grep 'f[0-9]*gr[A-Z]*\.*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gnu find, you can try

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/f[0-9]+gr[A-Z]+\.?.*'
```

Comment: Yeah that's another way to solve it :D thank you and this is my answer that i came to `ls | grep 'f[0-9]*gr[A-Z]*\.*'`

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the folder it's in?  If so, could you just search like so:

```
ls -l f*gr*
```

If not, you can try a find like this from the highest folder level necessary:

```
find . -name f*gr*
```